# Stray horizontal lines after converting from GeoJSON to topojson

Tags: leaflet, geojson, mapbox, topojson

After converting a GeoJSON file to topojson, and loading the topojson into Leaflet, stray lines appear in the resulting map.

Like this:

[image]

What is causing this? If I view the GeoJSON, these stray lines do not appear. I've played with the quantization behavior, and this does not seem to help. thanks.

(I am using Leaflet-Omnivore to digest the topojson.)

Comment: It is the common 180 Degree/Date Line issue https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/82 [See Bottom Links to Bugs Reported]

Comment: Thanks @Mapperz . The problem does not appear when using GeoJSON, though -- only topojson. Also, I see the problem if I load the topojson at mapshaper.org.